# Dynamic array javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm with a simple doubt in javascript.

I have a array load by server:

```
var dados = [{'ano':2016,'id':1,'mes':1,'valor':87},{'ano':2016,'id':2,'mes':2,'valor':17},{'ano':2016,'id':3,'mes':3,'valor':26}]
```

After I get the values that I need:

```
var valores = new Array();
for( var i=0; i < dados.length; i++) {
valores.push(dados[i].valor); 
}
```

Now is the doubt. How can I load the values to Chart.js?

```
var lineChartData = {
datasets : [{
    //ommited others configs..
    data :  valores (I would like load de values of valores here)      
}]}
```

Comment: What format does chart.js expect the `valores` data to be presented in, String, Array, Oblect..?

Comment: Well... `datasets: [{data: valores}]` is not supposed to do it correctly? Você já não está passando/atribuindo `valores` a `data`?

Comment: only calling var valores the chart doesnt work

Comment: As @DavidThomas' comment: What does chart.js expect?

Comment: @DavidThomas Chart.js needs a Array, if I put manually [18, 30, 10] its work.

Comment: Your code should be working(although you can use `Array.map`). Can you check if `valores` is accessible from the second block where you are defining `lineChartData`? Or add the structure of the code so that we can see where these two pieces of code is written, like if they are in different functions?

Comment: Sorry guys.. and thanks for your answers, but I found the problem in other part of my code. This part is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The `valores` var MUST BE a object instead of regular array type.So it should be something like this:

[image]

Look at the below code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
 var dados = [
  {'ano':2016,'id':1,'mes':1,'valor':87},
  {'ano':2016,'id':2,'mes':2,'valor':17},
  {'ano':2016,'id':3,'mes':3,'valor':26}
 ];
 var valores = {
  // labels like month (mes/mês - I noticed you're a portuguese speaker)
  labels: [], 
  datasets: [ 
   {label: null, data: []}
   //more items here whether you want
  ]        
 };
 
 for (var index in dados) {
  currData = dados[index];
  valores.labels.push('Mês ' + currData['mes']);
  valores.datasets[0]['data'].push(currData['valor']);
 }
 
 var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
 var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(valores);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a chart will take an array as an input with objects within it. Datasets cannot be an array, insted it should be a collection of objects.

your JSON data should be like

```
var lineChartData = {
    data : [{
      'valor':87
    },{
      'valor':22
    }]
}
```

Now Just see that you correct pass the above JSON to the chart.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but the docs show that dataset can be a array. [link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-data-structure)